# Calling two functions on click

Tags: javascript, html

I've to use 2 js function on clicking on a button/link.  One function is working fine this way

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closePopUp" onclick="resetEnquiryForm('enquiry-form');">close</a>
```

and popup is being closed properly.
Now I want to call one more function before popup get's closed this way

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closePopUp" onclick="return makeSelect('<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getId() ?>', '<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>retailon/productoption/values'); resetEnquiryForm('enquiry-form');">close</a>
```

But only first function is being called and popup is not being closed.
How I can make both the functions work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the problem is, you are returning from the first statement so the second one is not executed.

The easiest solution is to use another function which can call both these functions like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closePopUp" onclick="return doclick('<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getId() ?>', '<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>retailon/productoption/values', 'enquiry-form');">close</a>
```

then

```
function doclick(p1, p2, p3) {
    var res = makeSelect(p1, p2);
    resetEnquiryForm(p3);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function function1() {
 var prodId = '<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getId() ?>';
 var baseURL = '<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>retailon/productoption/values';
 makeSelect(prodId, baseURL);
 resetEnquiryForm('enquiry-form');
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closePopUp" onclick="function1();">close</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assigned the functions to different names, say `func1` and `func2` and call them together like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closePopUp" onclick="func1(); func2();">close</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want call two functions without any return value then use below code

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closePopUp" onclick="fun1(); fun2();">close</a>
```

2) If you want call two functions with any return value then use below code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closePopUp" onclick="return fun1(); fun2();">close</a>

function fun1() {
    fun2();
    return true;
}
```